# Не могу получить данные из изменённой таблицы QTableWidget в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Программа вроде работает правильно, выводит оценки в `self.marks`, но если раскомментировать функцию, которая должна изменённые элементы в таблице сохранять в переменную, то программа вылетает. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3


class Ui_AdminWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, AdminWindow):
        AdminWindow.setObjectName("AdminWindow")
        AdminWindow.resize(434, 513)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AdminWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.adding = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.adding.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 0, 101, 31))
        self.adding.setObjectName("adding")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 201, 221))
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.marks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 431, 191))
        self.marks.setObjectName("marks")
        self.marks.setColumnCount(0)
        self.marks.setRowCount(0)
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 101, 31))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.students = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.students.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 211, 31))
        self.students.setObjectName("students")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.school = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.school.setObjectName("school")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.school)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.class_student = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.class_student.setObjectName("class_student")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.class_student)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.gender = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.gender.setObjectName("gender")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.gender)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dob)
        self.save_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 180, 75, 23))
        self.save_data.setObjectName("save_data")
        self.delete_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.delete_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 180, 75, 23))
        self.delete_data.setObjectName("delete_data")
        self.upload_foto = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.upload_foto.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 89, 23))
        self.upload_foto.setObjectName("upload_foto")
        self.pass_manager = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pass_manager.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 230, 151, 23))
        self.pass_manager.setObjectName("pass_manager")
        AdminWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(AdminWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 434, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        AdminWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(AdminWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        AdminWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(AdminWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AdminWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, AdminWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AdminWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("AdminWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.adding.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Фото"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Школа"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Класс"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Пол"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.save_data.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "сохранить"))
        self.delete_data.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "удалить"))
        self.upload_foto.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pass_manager.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Менеджер паролей"))


class AdminWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_AdminWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AdminWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('AdminWindow')
        # self.marks.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed) из-за неё не работает
        self.table()
        self.modified = {}
        self.titles = None

    def table(self):
        subjects = ['русский', "математика", "литература", "физика", "английский"]
        appraisal = [("4 4 4 4", "5 5 5 5")]

        self.marks.setRowCount(len(subjects))  # заполняем таблицу с оценками
        self.marks.setColumnCount(3)
        self.marks.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Предмет', 'Оценки', 'Итог'))
        header = self.marks.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        i = 0
        for j in subjects:
            self.marks.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(j))
            if appraisal[0][0] is not None:
                self.marks.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(appraisal[0][0]))
                z = appraisal[0][0].split(" ")
                z = [i for i in z if i != ""]
                x = [int(i) for i in z]
                x = sum(x) / len(x)
                self.marks.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))
            else:
                self.marks.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
                self.marks.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
            i += 1

    def item_changed(self, item):
        # Если значение в ячейке было изменено,
        # то в словарь записывается пара: название поля, новое значение
        self.modified[self.titles[item.column()]] = item.text()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AdminWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Странно, что есть `self.titles` и `self.modified` ?  вы их пытаетесь использовать, но при этом они нигде не объявлены.

Comment: Поправил. Просто забыл вставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Просто забыл вставить `self.titles` и `self.modified`. Поправил.

Вы вставили данные переменные не в то место, т.е. после того места, когда они нужны в использовании.

Вы должны всегда помнить, что ключи в словаре - должны быть уникальными.
Вам недостаточно в качестве ключа использовать название колонки, надо добавить и позицию строки, тогда вы однозначно идентифицируете, что у вас в каждой ячейки таблицы.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3


class Ui_AdminWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, AdminWindow):
        AdminWindow.setObjectName("AdminWindow")
        AdminWindow.resize(434, 513)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AdminWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.adding = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.adding.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 0, 101, 31))
        self.adding.setObjectName("adding")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 201, 221))
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.marks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 431, 191))
        self.marks.setObjectName("marks")
        self.marks.setColumnCount(0)
        self.marks.setRowCount(0)
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 101, 31))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.students = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.students.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 211, 31))
        self.students.setObjectName("students")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.school = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.school.setObjectName("school")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.school)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.class_student = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.class_student.setObjectName("class_student")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.class_student)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.gender = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.gender.setObjectName("gender")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.gender)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dob)
        self.save_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 180, 75, 23))
        self.save_data.setObjectName("save_data")
        self.delete_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.delete_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 180, 75, 23))
        self.delete_data.setObjectName("delete_data")
        self.upload_foto = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.upload_foto.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 89, 23))
        self.upload_foto.setObjectName("upload_foto")
        self.pass_manager = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pass_manager.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 230, 151, 23))
        self.pass_manager.setObjectName("pass_manager")
        AdminWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(AdminWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 434, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        AdminWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(AdminWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        AdminWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(AdminWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AdminWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, AdminWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AdminWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("AdminWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.adding.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Фото"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Школа"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Класс"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Пол"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.save_data.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "сохранить"))
        self.delete_data.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "удалить"))
        self.upload_foto.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pass_manager.setText(_translate("AdminWindow", "Менеджер паролей"))


class AdminWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_AdminWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AdminWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.modified = {}                             # +
        self.titles = ('Предмет', 'Оценки', 'Итог')    # - None, + ('Предмет', 'Оценки', 'Итог')

        self.setWindowTitle('AdminWindow')
        self.marks.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)   #из-за неё не работает
        self.table()

### -       self.modified = {}
### -       self.titles = None


    def table(self):
        subjects = ['русский', "математика", "литература", "физика", "английский"]
        appraisal = [("4 4 4 4", "5 5 5 5")]

        self.marks.setRowCount(len(subjects))  # заполняем таблицу с оценками
        self.marks.setColumnCount(3)

#        self.marks.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Предмет', 'Оценки', 'Итог'))
        self.marks.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.titles)                      # +++


        header = self.marks.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        i = 0
        for j in subjects:
            self.marks.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(j))
            if appraisal[0][0] is not None:
                self.marks.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(appraisal[0][0]))
                z = appraisal[0][0].split(" ")
                z = [i for i in z if i != ""]
                x = [int(i) for i in z]
                x = sum(x) / len(x)
                self.marks.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))
            else:
                self.marks.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
                self.marks.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
            i += 1

    def item_changed(self, item):
        # Если значение в ячейке было изменено,
        # то в словарь записывается пара: название поля, новое значение

        self.modified['row:{} {}'.format(item.row(), self.titles[item.column()])] = item.text()

        # Посмотрите, что происходит, когда вы запускаете приложение 
        # и кода вы редактируете таблицу        
        print(f"self.modified: {self.modified}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AdminWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```